# Bacterial growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Marco works in a pharmaceutical laboratory and has to study the action
> of an antibiotic on the behavior of a certain type of bacterium that duplicates every 15 minutes.
>
> **a.** If there is 1 bacterium at the beginning of the experiment, how many bacteria will be there after 7 hours (assuming
> that no factors take over to alter the growth rate)?
>
> **b.** After 7 hours the antibiotic is used on the obtained culture of bacteria; it is observed that from this
> instant the number of bacteria in the culture halves every 20 minutes. How many bacteria will be there
> after 2 hours since the antibiotic was used?
> Leave all results expressed as powers of 2.

I have read that for bacterial growth the number of microorganisms in an exponentially growing population is always given by
$2^{n}$, where $n$ is the number of generations. I do not understand this part.

**The given solution:**

> For part a, generally, the number $N_t$ of cells at time $t$ and the initial number $N_0$ of cells are related by $N_t=N_0\times 2^n. \tag 1$ We have $n=\frac{7\ \text{hours}}{15\ \text{minutes}}=\frac{420\ \text{minutes}}{15\ \text{minutes}}=28,$ so at the end we have $2^{28}$ bacteria.
>
> For part b, we have $n'=\frac{20\ \text{hours}}{20\ \text{minutes}}=\frac{120\ \text{minutes}}{20\ \text{minutes}}=6,$ so at the end we have $$2^{28-6}=\frac{2^{28}}{2^6}=2^{22}$$ bacteria.

I do not understand the last step above. Is it more correct to write $2^{28}/2^6=2^{22}$ bacteria? Are the above formulas and steps correct? I await other solutions or a different formulation of the problem.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @user But $n$ and $n'$ should I write them as I did? I don't understand (only intuition) why I have to do $\text{bacteria}=2^{28-6}=2^{22}$? Is it more correct to write $\text{bacteria}=2^{28}/2^6=2^{22}$?

Comment: No, it is not more correct, it is the same.

Comment: "I did not understand why it should be $2^n.$" After the population doubles once, you have $N_0\times 2$ individuals. After it doubles again you have $N_0\times2\times2$. After 3 doublings you have $N_0\times2\times2\times2$. ...After $n$ doublings you have $N_0\times2^n$.

Comment: you can use the fist order growth equation to solve the problem. You can calculate the growth constant which will be ln(2)/15 (min)^(-1).

Comment: @04-jayeshkumargupta Why $\ln(2)/15 (min)^{-1}$?

Comment: @Sebastina In first order growth equations you can use the the formula: time taken to double population = ln(2)/k where k is growth constant. (In the previous comment I assumed you know what are first order equations).

Comment: @04-jayeshkumargupta Could you kindly give me an answer thank you very much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > a certain type of bacterium that duplicates every 15 minutes.
>
> I have read that for bacterial growth **the number of microorganisms in an exponentially growing population is always given by
> $2^{n},$** where $n$ is the number of generations. I do not understand this part.
>
> > generally, the number $N_t$ of cells at time $t$ and the initial number $N_0$ of cells are related by $N_t=N_0\times 2^n. \tag 1$

That boldfaced part above isn't correct: the number of organisms equals the product of $N_0$ and $2^n,$ rather than just $2^n.$ Formula $(1)$ is just saying this: after $n$ rounds of ***doubling***, the number of organisms becomes multiplied by ***two***, $n$ times.

In the above,  $n$ being the the number of generations refers to the number of rounds of the bacteria ***doubling*** in population size. On the other hand, if the population increases by $70\%$ after each round (that is, each specified period), then $N_t=N_0\times 1.7^n. \tag 2$

> > **b.** from this instant the number of bacteria in the culture halves every 20 minutes.
>
> > For part a,  we have $2^{28}$ bacteria.
> >
> > For part b, we have $n'=\frac{20\ \text{hours}}{20\ \text{minutes}}=\frac{120\ \text{minutes}}{20\ \text{minutes}}=6,$ so at the end we have $$2^{28-6}=\frac{2^{28}}{2^6}=2^{22}$$ bacteria.
>
> I do not understand the last step above. Is it more correct to write $2^{28}/2^6=2^{22}$ bacteria?

Part b is no longer using formula $(1);$ here, every round/period, the bacteria are now ***halving*** instead of ***doubling***, so the formula becomes $N_t=N_0\times 0.5^n, \tag 3$ where $N_0$ is now Part a's answer. So, this time, we have $$N_t=2^{28}\times0.5^6.$$

---

**Addendum**

Formula $(1)$ refers specifically to population doubling. Observe that we can generalise it: the number of bacteria immediately after the $n$th period is $$N_n=(1+r)^nN_0,$$ where $r$ is the population-size increase per period. So,

- $r=1$ corresponds to the population increasing by $100\%,$ i.e., the population doubling,
- $r=0.59$ corresponds to the population increasing by $59\%,$
- $r=-0.5$ corresponds to the population *decreasing* by $50\%,$ i.e., the population halving.

Comment: I have not understood $1.7^n$ and the 70%, like $0.5^n$.

Comment: How do I find $2^{28}$ from the relation $N_t=N_0\times 1.7^n$?

Comment: By what criterion is base 2 changed?

Comment: @Sebastiano 3. I don't understand your question. $\quad$ 2. As I said, the $N_0=2^{28}$ in part b refers to part a's answer $N_t.$ $\quad$ 1. $N_0\times 1.7^n$ means take $N_0,$ multiply it by $1.7,$ then repeat this multiplication $n$ times; multiplying $N_0$ by $1.7$ means that the result is 70% bigger than $N_0;$ multiplying $N_0$ by $2$ means that the result is double of $N_0;$ multiplying $N_0$ by $0.5$ means that the result is half of $N_0.$

Comment: How you find $2^{28}$ starting from the formula $N(t)=N_0\times 2^n$? And Why you put like the base $ 1.7
 $ and after $0.5$. But this $2$ is not fixed?

Comment: 1. If you are asking how part a was obatained: $N(t)=1\times2^{28}=2^{28};$ did you not understand your quoted solution of part a??? $\quad$ 2. You have to really read what I wrote in my above comments and Answer. $\quad$ 3. By the way, are you using someone else's account to post this question? This current post appears incongruous with Sebastiano's previous posts.

Comment: Absolutely NO! why this unfounded doubt?

Comment: I did not understand this 1.7 and this 0.5 from where they come out of the problem data.

Comment: I have not understood the $N_t=N_0\times 1.7^n$ and the reason because you put 1.7 and consider 70%. The same for the $(3)$. The formula $N_0 \times 2^n$ is that of doubling and $N_0 \times (1/2)^n$ and when is half reduced? So the formula must always be adjusted?

Comment: @Sebastiano I added an addendum. If necessary, please re-read point #1 in my first comment.

Comment: Why in my case there is an increasing by 70%? I have understood the $N_n=(1+r)^nN_0$

Comment: @Sebastiano Please note the word "if" in the introduction to formula $(2);$ this word introduces a hypothetical scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Ans a) We can use the formula $N=N_0e^{kt}$

where $N$ is initial number of bacteria.
they have given the time for bacteria to double ($t$) hence  $$k=\frac{\ln 2}{t}$$
after plugging in the values you get,$$N=e^{\frac{\ln 2}{15}\times 7\times 60}$$
which will come out to be $2^{28}$.

Ans b) Now the bacteria is halfling very 20 mins. Hence the net growth constant will be $$k=-\frac{\ln 2}{20}$$

Now the initial number of bacteria is $2^{28}$ so, $$N=2^{28}e^{\frac{-\ln 2}{20}\times 2\times 60}=2^{28-6}=2^{22}.$$

Comment: Plz forgive me for not using LaTex as i dont know how to use it so i coudnt write my answer more beautifully. (And i am assuming you know first order equations)

Comment: I have seen . But you where take $\ln 2$?

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand your question. Can you plz rephrase the question

Comment: Why you have written $k=\frac{\ln 2}{t}$? What is the reason.

Comment: the formula can be derived from the growth equation itself by taking N as 2No and then solving for t. That t has a special name and it it called doubling time. Since they have given the time taken to double the population of bacteria it can be used to find the growth constant.